# Support for ElasticSearch index pattern wildcard other than star?

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard

Does elasticsearch index pattern support wildcards other than '*' but would match ex. a single character?

I'm trying to solve an issue with wrong index matching that someone implemented:
Indexes are called `index-{customername}-{date}` (ex. `index-google-2020-12-31)` but author did not consider that `{customername}` can contain dash. As a result query
`curl localhost:9200/index-google-company-*/_search` would also match index `index-google-company-spies-me-2020-12-31`.
I could fing a symbol that is not allowed in the ID (ex. `~`) but then I need to re-index all the data.

Comment: What about regexp queries? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html

Comment: RegExp query would restrict data - but, as far as I understand, it wouldn't filter the indices accessed as each query term is executed separately (thus more search criteria means slower search). Unless I am wrong here - then, please, correct me

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. Maybe you mention about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54580637/1068246

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted. To specify each index - it is not very flexible (having one index per day I would need to specify 365 names to search within whole year of data → several kilobytes added to the URL).
And so answer to my question is: no, no other wildcards are supported.